# How do you remove cities_light objects from a django postgresql database?

Tags: django, heroku, django-models

I've installed cities_light in my free heroku database, with cities from two countries using

```
heroku run python manage.py cities_light
```

However, I'm trying to remove the cities of one of the two countries. How would I do this? Is there a cities_light command that will delete all City, Region, Country objects in the database? I've looked in the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be such a command.
Thanks!